# PowerShell Database Connection Trouble Shooting

Tags: database, powershell

A few months ago, I wrote a short Powershell script that opened a connection to an Access database, entered data into a table, then closed the connection. This script was used successfully in other instances, only needing to change the database and table name.

Now, when I run the script, the data is not being written into the database (even after a manual Refresh All). If I run a SQL script (no PowerShell), no problems. The end goal is to pull data from TextBox TextArea on a web page, and *INSERT INTO* the database. I've tried copy/past into PowerShell, running portions through PowerShell ISE, and am not seeing the database updates. Running out of ideas on how to check/trouble shoot this one. Anyone have ideas?

NOTES:

1. My account is a regular user account
2. No additional libraries/software/modules/etc will be installed
3. There have been some new security "upgrades" over the past few weeks
4. We don't have AJAX, PHP or (for Java) JDBC

CODE: (hand jammed, not copy/paste - pardon any typos!):

```
try {
    $DatabaseName = "dataBaseName"
    $ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$DatabaseName"
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $ConnectionString
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand $Query, $Connection
    $Connection.Open()
    $Adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $Command
    $Dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    [void] $Adapter.Fill($DataSet)  
    $datasetTables = $Dataset.Table[0]

# assigning values to test initial conneciton
    $pocName = "Daffy Duck"
    $pocEmail = "dd@mailservice.com"
    $pocPhone = "123-4567"
    $address = "P. O. Box 123A"
    $city = "Supai"
    $state = "AZ"
    $zip = "86435"

    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO dbTable ([NAME],[EMAIL],[PHONE],[ADDRESS],[CITY],[STATE],[ZIP])
            VALUES ('$pocName','$pocEmail','$pocPhone','$address','$city','$state','$zip');"
    $Command.CommandText = $insertQuery
    $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
}
catch {Out-Null
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

***Update and follow up question.***

Still working on this one. Was told that a suspected patch update wasn't "the culprit", and that the OLE provider I was implementing (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) is old, and to try Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0. I tried this, but it didn't work. Here's the version of MS Access to which I have to use:

*MS Office Professional Plus 2019
Version 1808 (Build 10400.20007)
Microsoft Access 2019 (16.0.10400.20007) 64-bit*

Given the code (above), aside from the *$ConnectionString* variable, can anyone see what else that needs to change?

***More information:***

Ran the following script to get which providers are available to me on the current system. Hopefully the output (below the script) is useful. Can anyone decipher for me? I'm a Solaris/BSD Unix guy, not a Microsoft guy.

```
foreach ($provider in [system.data.oledb.olebenumerator]::getrootenumerator()) {
$v = new-object psobject
for ($i - 0; $i -lt $provider.fieldcount; $i++) {
$v | add-member noteproperty $provider.getname($i) $provider.getvalue($i)
}$v
}
```

The output from the script gave the following output (edited):

```
SOURCES_NAME: SQLOLEDB
SOURCES_PARSENAME: {*deleted*}
SOURCES_DESCRIPTION: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
SOURCES_TYPE: 1
SOURCES_ISPARENT: False
SOURCES_CLSID: {*deleted*}

SOURCES_NAME:SQLNCLI11
SOURCES_PARSENAME: {*deleted*}
SOURCES_DESCRIPTION: SQL Server Native Client 11.0
SOURCES_TYPE:1
SOURCES_ISPARENT:False
SOURCES_CLSID:{*deleted*}

SOURCES_NAME:ADsDSOObject
SOURCES_PARSENAME:{*deleted*}
SOURCES_DESCRIPTION:OLE B Provider for Microsoft Directory Services
SOURCES_TYPE:1
SOURCES_ISPARENT:False
SOURCES_CLSID:{*deleted*}
```

Not quite sure how to phase my next question other than how does this output affect my script and lack of connecting to the database?

Comment: Perhaps you have updated the SQL Server driver.  Are you using `TrustServerCertificate`?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Try removing the ```try … catch``` while you’re investigating - you’re swallowing any exceptions that might contain useful troubleshooting info…

Comment: Also, you should consider using parameterised sql queries to insert values rather than interpolating the values into a plain text sql string - that’s a massive sql injection attack waiting to happen…

Comment: Do you have a typo : $connection.Clode()  You may have a share issue if the database is not closed and you try opening with another app.

Comment: @jdweng - yes, it's a typo, thanks - if you read my post prior to the code, I did mention typing in the code, vice copy/paste.

Comment: @mclayton - good point - am too focused on trying to get it working

Comment: @ mclayton - will try without try--catch and post any results. Thanks!

Comment: @lit - thanks for your suggestion; cannot implement/check since JDBC is not (nor will be) installed by the admins (already asked).

Comment: @mclayton - tried running code without try/catch. Apparently there have been changes on my local machine as I cannot connect via $Connection statement. Getting an error: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." Will have ask the admins about this one.

Comment: Not sure how to close this thread, as I believe this will never be resolved for the system upon which I work. There's no provision for developers, nor are there plans to expand capabilities.



Thanks everyone who tried to help me. Your comments and suggestions were great - unlike this system.